# oracle 12c, procedure created with compilation error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm new to Oracle, and just begin to learn it on a internet course.

Here's the PL/SQL I typed:

```
create or replace procedure xl_2 is
declare
v_ename varchar2(20);
begin
select ename into v_ename from emp where empno=&no;
dbms_output.put_line('Ename'||v_ename);
end;
/
```

and here's the problem after SHOW errors:

```
2/1      PLS-00103: 出现符号 "DECLARE"在需要下列之一时：   begin function pragma     procedure subtype type <an identifier>     <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete     exists prior external language  符号 "begin" 被替换为 "DECLARE" 后继续。  
9/0      PLS-00103: 出现符号 "end-of-file"在需要下列之一时：   ( begin case     declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod null pragma     raise return select update while with <an identifier>     <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<     continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback     savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
```

I typed exactly same with the course sample, but got errors.

Is there something new in 12c to create procedures?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `declare` is used in anonymous PL/SQL blocks but not procedures. "I typed exactly same with the course sample" If true you need to find a better course.

Comment: Thanks, APC. I'm new to Oracle, used to learn PHP in another course of the teacher's. Maybe you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Rermove `declare`

```
create or replace procedure xl_2 is
v_ename varchar2(20);
begin
select ename into v_ename from emp where empno=&no;
dbms_output.put_line('Ename'||v_ename);
end;
/
```

Declare is for anonymous block not for procedure. Another problem may be `&no` This will be replaced when procedure is created. I think you need:

```
create or replace procedure xl_2(p_empno number) is
v_ename varchar2(20);
begin
select ename into v_ename from emp where empno=p_empno;
dbms_output.put_line('Ename'||v_ename);
end;
/
```

To be able to call procedure for different `empno`.

Comment: Hi Kacper, Thank you for such a quick response. The procedure is created without errors.

Comment: In 12c, declare is not needed anymore?

Comment: `declare` is needed for anonymous block or for trigger but not for procedure. Nothing changed in 12c

Comment: Thanks for the guide. Yes, that's exactly what I need to do. But when I type 'exec xl_2(7788)', the console just prints a message that the procedure is completed, without the output of DBMS_OUTPUT. 7788 is the empno for "SCOTT".

Comment: @Michael You might need to run this first: `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;`

Comment: MT0, So silly of me. I typed 'show serveroutput',,,, solved, thank you.